# F120B Cubic Symmetric Graph

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

Here is a rolling octahedron version of the [Nauru graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nauru_graph).

[image]

Each triangle side connects to the orientation the octahedron corresponding to rolling over that edge.

The F120B cubic symmetric graph can be obtained by rolling an icosahedron with 12 labelled faces.

[image]

In the version above the triangles overlap.  Can someone make a version of F120B with 120 triangles?  Ideally, almost all of the triangles would have a direct edge connection to two other triangles.  The girth of F120B is 10, corresponding to rolling the icosahedron on the middle band of 10 triangles.

Perhaps one of these might work. I don't know an easy way to check.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused about the setup. If all vertices are labeled and the identical positions of the icosahedron are those that are a parallel transport of one another, then rolling the icosahedron as a die gives only 60 positions. What is the additional transformation that gives 120 positions?

Comment: @Maxim The triangles have two distinct orientations: $\triangleleft\;\triangleright\;$, and on an icosahedron it's possible to return to the same face and be in the other orientation.

Comment: @nickgard OK, I see, so a face can have six orientations, and thus there isn't a direct correspondence to rotations that map an icosahedron to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$                            $
[image]

Comment: Wow.  How do the empty edges for 1 and 2 match up?